# Sylius/Symfony3 You have requested a non-existent service

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sylius, symfony-3.1

Anyone have any expertise trouble-shooting Symfony 3 and Sylius?
I created a new entity, I followed the instructions step by step from the [documentation here](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/cookbook/custom-model.html)

When I run:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

it successfully creates a new table in the db that corresponds with the new entity/model, but when I try to interact with that table I get:

> You have requested a non-existent service "sylius.repository.status_code".

I've re-created the entity three times now and cannot figure out where I went wrong.

```
$statusCodes = $this->container->get('sylius.repository.status_code');
$statusCode = $statusCodes->find(1);
dump($statusCode); exit;
```

Comment: Did you try to clear cache?

Comment: yes, no change in result

Comment: Try to debug the service-container in the CLI: bin/console debug:container and look which services are defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chalk this one up to inexperience....  again.  The entity was successfully created and mapped, I was just trying to access it in the wrong way.  Instead of using the default way-

`$this->container->get('sylius.repository.table_name');`

I learned that you need to use the bundle name in the db call.  example-
`$this->container->get('bundle_name.repository.table_name');`

Rookie move-